# How can I create column in list which it able to change data (lookup column) in next column?

Tags: list, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, lookup-column, column

How can I create column in list which it able to change data (lookup column) in next column?

For example: I have three lists with datas(names, numbers and adress) and I have other list with two columns - first column is choose column with Name, Number, Adres fields and second is lookup column depend on first column. When I add new item to this list and I choose Name in first column in second column I will able to choose date from lookup Name list but when I choose in first column Number in next column I will able to choose date from lookup Number list etc...

How can I do it?

I use SP Foundation and Designer 2010.

Best regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hope following links will help,

http://howididit-sharepoint.blogspot.in/2012/04/filtering-lookup-columns.html

http://sharepoint-works.blogspot.in/2012/02/cascading-dropdown-or-filtered-values.html#.UJdVvMXqkdg

Comment: Thanks a lot for above links, I will read that articles and I hope it help me with solution. Best regards,